# How to extract a river profile using specific distance intervals

Tags: qgis, dem, qgis-2.16

I'm using QGIS 2.16 and I'd like to extract a river profile from a DEM applying user-defined intervals (e.g. every 100 m of horizontal distance). I get profiles using both the "Profile tool" and the "Profile from lines" SAGA process. However, I cannot control how those profiles are generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a river centreline you could convert the centreline into spaced points using for example the [Qchainage plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/) to create points spaced at the desired interval.

Then use the [point sampling plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) to add the DEM elevations to the points.

Then export the attribute table out into excel or R or somesuch programme and plot the profile.

Be careful of the direction of your centreline so that it calculates the points from upstream to downstream.

Comment: For the creation of points, in processing he can also use OGR: create points along lines or QGIS vector geometry tools: create points along lines or GRASS: v.to.points.